# Find $\sqrt[4]{z}$ where $z=e^{it}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find $\sqrt[4]{z}$ where $z=e^{it}$

$$\sqrt[4]{z}=z^{\frac{1}{4}}=e^{logz^{\frac{1}{4}}}=e^{\frac{1}{4}logz}$$

$$\sqrt[4]{e^{it}}=e^{\frac{1}{4}log(e^{it})}$$

What is $log(e^{it})$? is it?

$log(e^{it})=ln|e^{it}|+iArg(e^{it})=ln|1|+iArg(e^{it})=0+iArg(e^{it})$

But what is $Arg(e^{it})$?

Comment: Do you mean $e^{\frac{1}{4}it}$?

Comment: @SakethMalyala I am just looking at the exponent with out $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: log(e^it) = it umm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $\log (e^{it})$ is the exponent to gives to $e$ to find $e^{it}$.  Since the exponential function in the field of complex numbers is periodic (with period $2\pi i$) this ''inverse function'' of the exponential is not really a function but has different possible values (it is called a [multivalued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function)), so we have: $\log (e^{it})=it+2k\pi i$.

This means that we have:
$$
\sqrt[4]{z}=e^{i(\frac{t+2k\pi}{4})}
$$

that, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ gives four different values:

$$
k=0 \quad \rightarrow \quad z_1=e^{i\frac{t}{4}}
$$
$$
k=1 \quad \rightarrow \quad z_1=e^{i(\frac{t}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2})}
$$
$$
k=2 \quad \rightarrow \quad z_1=e^{i(\frac{t}{4}+\pi)}
$$
$$
k=3 \quad \rightarrow \quad z_1=e^{i(\frac{t}{4}+\frac{3\pi}{4})}
$$

Comment: "is the exponent to gives to $e$ to find $e^{it}$" you meant?  is the exponent to gives to $log$? ok got it never mind!

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused as to what you are asking for, but $\displaystyle \sqrt[4]{e^{it}}=\boxed{\large e^{\frac{1}{4}(it+2πni)}}$

This is also $\large \displaystyle e^{\frac{it}{4}}, ie^{\frac{it}{4}}, -e^{\frac{it}{4}}, -ie^{\frac{it}{4}}$